# Run oracle procedure with cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am not experienced with db (actually not at all) and I face a problem:
I have oracle 11g and I am using PL/SQL developer.
I have a simple procedure :

```
type t_ref_cursor is ref cursor;

procedure fakeProc (
       io_cursor        in out t_ref_cursor
      )
   is
      begin

      open io_cursor for
      SELECT * from myTable;

 end fakeProc;
```

Now I want to run it as a SQL window (not in a test window)
What I am trying to run:

```
 v_cur         cursor;
 begin
    fakeProc(:v_cur);
 end;
```

I get errors:
ORA-00900:Invalid SQL statement
ORA-01008:not all variables bound

So can you point me the right way to run a procedure like this(with begin -end)?

Comment: This exception block has no purpose, except hiding any error that you may encounter. Remove it!

Comment: what is t_ref_cursor ?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat:it's irrelevant...

Comment: what is t_ref_cursor ??

Comment: @Teshte: is a ref cursor

Comment: so a type ?..use SYS_REFCURSOR

Comment: @Nianios That's why it's a comment, not an answer. I've seen many places where it's an habit to write such nasty exception blocks, I was only pointing that it's a very bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this :

```
declare v_cur         SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  fakeProc(v_cur);
end;
```

And the procedure looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FAKEPROC( 
    io_cursor        in out SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
IS 
      begin

      open io_cursor for
      SELECT * from resource_map;


END FAKEPROC;
```

Don't forget to close cursor after finishing working with it.

Comment: @Nianios don't forget to `close cursor` after finishing working with it

Answer (score 1):

Version 7.1.4 of PL/SQL Developer doesn't support ref cursor:

```
SQL> VARIABLE p_cur REFCURSOR;
REFCURSOR not supported
```

Later versions may support them (in a command window), or you can use SQL*Plus. This is a direct copy-paste from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc (p_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3     OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT * FROM dual;
  4  END;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> -- declare variable
SQL> VARIABLE p_cur REFCURSOR;
SQL> BEGIN
  2     prc(:p_cur);
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print p_cur

DUM
---
X
```

Comment: I have version 10.0.2. I tried your code in a SQL window  and I get error in the first line (invalid SQL statement)

Comment: PLSQL dev command window is very much like command-line `sqlplus` but with less features. You can keep using all the cool features of PLSQL dev and run your scripts with `sqlplus` -- that's what I usually do.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I accepted Teshte's solution. Thanks for your time and advices